# Could there exist a quantum virus which breaks someone's body down to fundamental particles?

Tags: diseases, nuclear, strong-force, weak-force

In the Animorphs series K.A. Applegate mentions:

> A quantum virus. It breaks down the very forces that holds subatomic particles together. It can take weeks or even months of agony as your body grows weaker and weaker and breaks down into the fundamental particles...

So is it possible for such a virus to exist also what kind of gruesome effect will it have *as your body grows weaker and ultimately breaks down to fundamental particles.* Bonus if horrible agony can be evolved to the highest possible extent.

Also for the sake of simplicity assume that the virus breaks down both the strong and weak nuclear forces.

**Edit:** In the series Applegate writes that the virus is a disease in space time implying that is not a living being or anything we know of nor will we ever know about in the near future. However (for further simplicity) we can assume that the virus is non-reproductive entity but immortal except if treated with the correct medicine which is not available at present to the victims. Also the virus works by contact which means that if your hand comes into contact with the viruses it is the first organ to be doomed and then slowly the rest of your body

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you can gather from other answers already given here:

- Your "virus" wouldn't be a biological construct;
- It would be orders of magnitude smaller than a proper virus.

I should mention then something called a [strangelet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strangelet). Now there is a lot of physics to this beast, but TL;DR:

- This is a thing made of quarks, just like protons and neutrons;
- Protons and neutrons are nuclear matter. Strangelets, on the other hand, are [strange matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_matter) (particle physicists come up with the best terms ever);
- A strangelet should be at least as big as an atom, but here's the cool thing: if the current model for them is right, they grow like [katamaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katamari_Damacy)!

From the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strangelet#Dangers):

> If the strange matter hypothesis is correct and its surface tension is larger than the aforementioned critical value, then a larger strangelet would be more stable than a smaller one. One speculation that has resulted from the idea is that a strangelet coming into contact with a lump of ordinary matter could convert the ordinary matter to strange matter. This "ice-nine"-like disaster scenario is as follows: one strangelet hits a nucleus, catalyzing its immediate conversion to strange matter. This liberates energy, producing a larger, more stable strangelet, which in turn hits another nucleus, catalyzing its conversion to strange matter. In the end, all the nuclei of all the atoms of Earth are converted, and Earth is reduced to a hot, large lump of strange matter.

What I could not find anywhere is the rate at which a strangelet would grow and convert nuclear matter.

Since this is all hypothetical and you are going into sci-fi, you could use strangelets for inspiration. It goes like this: someone touches a strangelet somehow, and now their body is slowly but surely coming apart. Let's say that it would take ten years for the whole body of an adult to be converted into a strangelet... This is so slow, that the body may somehow "excrete" or otherwise get rid of part of the strangelets, and rebuild some parts of it somehow... But the person would be afflicted by symptoms not unlike those of cancer/acute radiation syndrome and leprosy, with the body destroying itself from inside out.

As a bonus: a strangelet will affect any nuclear matter, not just living matter... So your patients would have a more extreme version of the midas touch. Anything that comes in contact with them, even the very air they breath, is doomed to slow destruction. Just imagine. Someone afflicted with *strangeletitis* sets foot on a planet. That planet may last for millenia or even millions of years, but everything in it will be converted to plasma as the eons pass as surely as two plus two equals four.

This also makes this "disease" the most contagious thing in the universe. It is the very matter of the cosmos that is getting sick. The only way to prevent spread is throwing whatever planet is showing any case of this into a black hole.

Comment: would it be possible for someone to use this as a weapon and accelerate the disintegration into particles?

Comment: @Sky possibly. I don't have the knowledge to describe how that could be done... But as Einstein said, when someone says something is impossible, they're probably wrong.

Comment: if you throw that into a black hole - won't you get a *strange* black hole?

Comment: @Tom yeah, one that spews strange hawkings radiation, which might accelerate the spreading of the overall destruction.

Answer (score 9):

## If you invoke magic, yes. Otherwise, no.

If you invoke magic, then yes, such a thing can exist. If you stick with known science, no.

There are no known physics or even theories that spontaneously can make the Strong or Weak forces shrug their shoulders and say "Naw, I quit... this is no fun now". So you will have to invoke magic here.

If you do that, your "disease" could credibly act pretty much as severe [acute radiation syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_radiation_syndrome). What this means is that it breaks DNA apart which in turn means that the cells of the body stops working, unable to divide and replenish. This means that your body gradually break down over a few days, starting with the gastrointestinal tract.

For a graphic account of how this happens, read about the "[Demon Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_core)" that killed physicists Louis Slotin and Harry Daghlian.

Comment: Why just DNA? This virus would destroy **any** atom, wouldn't it? The very moment the forces are weakened enough to destroy DNA they should also be weakened enough to destroy oxygen or ATP or another of the innumerable system the failing of which would cause the immediate death of the affected person.

Comment: OP asked for a gruesome way to kill the person. We know that ARS is horrendously gruesome, and protracted over several days.

Comment: Sure, that would be a gruesome death, but it is not possible within the limits given by the OP. The OP didn't permit selective weakening of the strong and weak nuclear forces. If this happens on some part of the body it's happening everywhere else as well.

Comment: @Annonymus So you are saying that we have this powerful super-virus, that has the extraordinary magic ability that can it mess with the forces of nature, but then you claim it cannot be made so that it targets DNA?! I am sorry but that was just **silly**! :) Targeting DNA is what viruses do for a living... literally so! Viruses cannot survive and spread in the body without attacking DNA. Essentially you are saying that the realistic premise — which exists in the real world already — is not acceptable, but that the magic, fantastic and physics-breaking premise is A-OK.

Comment: I think @Annonymus's point was more that such a virus (or whatever) would target any type of cells equally. Sure, it would happen to DNA, but it would happen to everything else *as well*.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Eh, yeah... that is what radiation does as well! Unless you have a very local source of the radiation, your entire body's DNA takes a beating. In fact, radiation would probably more uniformly affect the body than viruses since viruses can be extremely organ-specific. For example: you know that case of chicken-pox you had a child? It is very likely that some of those viruses still live in your body, in your **nerves**, and when they feel like it, they will propagate along those nerves to give you Shingles (Bältros på svenska). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shingles

Comment: But again I must stress that the objection is silly. You invoke physics breaking magic to achieve this thing, but then you also say that it cannot do what it already does in real life. That is just so silly. It is like saying saying that some magic comes along that can make humans fly; no specifications beyond that, so how they fly is **entirely open to choice**... but then say that no, they cannot do aerobatics, ever... because that is just not realistic. Come on! Du silar mygg och sväljer kameler nu...

Comment: What I actually meant to say was that the OP didn't give us this tool to work with, even if in your opinion that doesn't make sense, and you should at the very least note in your answer that, to produce this effect, you had the virus act only on DNA, leaving everything else untouched. Btw, viruses do not target other DNA. Their goal is to be copied (usually by injecting themselves into the nuclei of other cells). If they can do this without interacting with the host's original DNA then they will do so.

Comment: @Annonymus "You had the virus act only on DNA, leaving everything else untouched". No I did not. That is an entirely faulty assumption at your end. Ionizing radiation does not specifically target DNA and leave everything else untouched either. If you get hit by a massive dose it will ionize atoms and molecules throughout your **entire** body and wildly mess with your body chemistry. But that is not what kills you... it is the breakdown of DNA that causes the cells to stop working. The DNA is the most critical part of your cells. Without that, **nothing** works and the cell dies.

Comment: @Annonymus and Michael Kjörling, I am sorry but I have to ask: are you objecting to improve the answer or just to be querulous? Because right now I am only seeing two people objecting for the sake of objecting. Since we have already invoked physics-breaking **magic**, pulling a **realism** card on that, and on as weak grounds as you do, seems silly in the extreme to me now. Come on... work **with** me here instead of objecting just for the heck of it.

Comment: In radiation exposure DNA breakdown is what kills you first, but in a weakening of the strong and weak nuclear forces it isn't. As I explained above, there are other factors which would kill you before symptoms of radiation exposure even appear. I assure you that I am not trying to antagonize you, but rather feel that your answer may be misleading to somebody who does not have a thorough understanding of chemistry and physics. The grounds on which I am stating my objection do not seem weak or silly at all to me.

Comment: @Annonymus "but in a weakening of the strong and weak nuclear forces it isn't". Yes it is. Because what you do with that magic to make atoms suddenly go **missing**. That is just as detrimental as breaking the DNA strands through ionization. Also — unless you wish to break yet some more physics laws, such as **The Law of Conservation of Energy** — such disappearances of atoms will cause **massive** bursts of ionizing radiation where it happens, which will break even more DNA strands. So I stand by my point: you are being silly and trying to poke holes in this just for the heck of it.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors Sure, DNA **will** break. But at that point you'll be dead already because cellular respiration stopped in all your cells simultaneously when ATP broke down. It doesn't matter if DNA breaks down as well as that will kill you more slowly. I also find your continued insistence on my intention of antagonizing you offensive as, even in the case in which your argument held, my action would have been derived not from hostile intentions, but misinformation.

Comment: @Annonymus Now you are being **more** specific than I am! Where did you get the notion that only all the ATP breaks down but the rest of the body remains untouched?! Make up your mind here: either this virus targets things or it does not. You just postulated that all - or a significant amount of - ATP is targeted.

Comment: I never said that **only** all the ATP breaks. I merely said that all of it breaks. Along with this lots of other molecules will break as well, including DNA. This will cause you to die immediatly, rather than letting your body break down slowly as would happen in the case of radiation exposure. I have already said this in earlier comments but it seems you have misunderstood. I therefore suggest that we move this discussion to chat to avoid cluttering the comments.

Answer (score 1):

A biological virus is a string of RNA in a protein shell, that attached itself to host DNA in order to propagate. This makes it the size of a molecule, with all the physical and chemical limitations therein.

An atom is a couple of orders of magnitude smaller than a molecule; the nucleus is about 5 orders smaller still. At the quantum level, an object is on the level of being detected only as a statistical probability. Your virus would have to knowingly manipulate forces that it cannot reasonably measure, while ensuring it itself is not negatively affected; an atom is an atom, after all, and your virus contains several thousand.

There's easier ways to make a living than as a microscopic quantum physicist (you can't even apply for research grants ;P). Given that evolution follows the path of least resistance, your quantum virus is unlikely to exist **as a biological organism**.

Comment: It's not just unlikely, it's impossible. The strong and weak nuclear forces are constants in our universe. Nothing pertaining to it can change them.

Comment: @Annonymus  "not *#&&@y likely" loses a lot without the expletive ;)

Answer (score 1):

**If such a virus does exist, the universe as we know it would be gone within a few hundreds of millions of years or so.**

Working at such small levels, the *virus* would not make any difference between a living body or a stone or magma. It will simply go on working as a slow hydrogen bomb (yes, when you split atomic particles apart, you are actually converting part of the mass into energy. this energy comes from the strong nuclear force which provides some of the mass in the atomic nuclei. and that is precisely what nuclear bombs do).

And as a *virus*, it will generate at least tens (and a nuclear scientist would wager in favor of billions) of copies of itself from each atom it destroys. Depending on your whim, the virus could travel from one place to another at the speed of light, or more horrible yet, through quantum entanglement.

Farewell to the universe as we know it ... Oh, and it would be a horror to watch planets, moons, stars, solar systems, and in fact whole galaxies exploding to pieces as quintillions upon quintillions of such virus produce incomprehensible amount of heat as they take apart countless atoms in those heavenly bodies.

I would desire to be long dead before that. It would be a mortally horrific sight ...

Comment: Actually a hydrogen bomb releases energy by *fusing* nuclei. Only heavy nuclei like uranium release energy if you split them; for light atoms like oxygen or carbon, it *costs* energy.

Comment: Both types of nuclear bombs (fission and fusion) convert some of the strong nuclear force into EM energy waves. That is what was intended.

Comment: But for light atoms, you cannot release energy by *fission* (and for heavy ones not by fusion). And breaking down to fundamental particles is fission, not fusion. And BTW, if you broke down uranium to fundamental particles (as opposed to medium-weight nuclei) you'd also have to invest energy.

Comment: sigh. just **_sigh_**